# ASP.NET MVC: User.Identity.Name not available even when page is authenticated

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I've been receiving some error reports recently that seem to suggest that sometimes User.Identity.Name is `NULL` or different to what it should be (the authenticated user's username), even when the page is authenticated:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyAction() 
{
    string username = User.Identity.Name;
    Member member = memberRepository.GetMemberByUserName(username); 

    member.something // fails with a null reference exception
}
```

The `GetMemberByUserName()` method uses Linq to SQL to retrieve the member.

```
public Member GetMemberByUsername(string username)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        return null;

    return db.Members.SingleOrDefault(d => d.username.Equals(username));
}
```

**Under which circumstances would this happen? Do I need to check if User.Identity.Name is `NULL` whenever I use it?**

Of course, the User.Identity.Name could be a red herring, and it could be that the database is just not returning anything. I would probably have expected an exception to be thrown if this was the case, though.

**EDIT:**
This is an intermittent issue - it could be that an authenticated user refreshes once, the User.Identity.Name is correct and the member is retrieved, and then on a second refresh, the member is not retrieved.

Comment: The only return case possible here is to return null or an empty Member.

Comment: Examine what `User.Identity.Name` returns and if such value exist in your database. Hope it'll give you hint.

Comment: It's definitely in the database. This code errors out intermittently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it could be that the database is just not returning anything. I would probably have expected an exception to be thrown if this was the case, though.

No, it won't. `SingleOrDefault` will return a single record, no record, or **throw an exception if more than one record exists**.

`Single` will return a single record, or **throw an exception if no record or more than one exists**.

Could be a few things. Maybe you have case sensitivity issues with the `String.Equals`.

It's still possible that `Request.IsAuthenticated` (what `[Authorize]` looks at) is true, but there is no identity. Particulary true in custom authentication systems (such as attempting to decrypt the forms authentication ticket), and you haven't specified what your using.

Also, make sure the `Username` field is backed by a **unique index**, to provide server-side guarantees that `SingleOrDefault` will NEVER throw an exception.

I would put some try/catch in your controller actions, and setup ELMAH to catch the exceptions.

Comment: I don't believe the User.Identity.Name not returning anything is really an issue. Usually, this would throw an exception as Identity would be null thus making the Name property not accessible. So I would concentrate on the db stuff as RPM1984 recommended.

Comment: @Jeff - maybe "Name" is empty. We have no idea, we can only speculate based on the info given.

Comment: I had figured that it would throw an exception because the user definitely does exist in the database - this is an intermittent error that occurs.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
public Member GetMemberByUsername(string username)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
       return null;

    return db.Members.SingleOrDefault(d => d.username.Equals(username));
}
```

Comment: Oops, sorry - mistyped my question. That's actually what the method says. Answer edited.